# ASP.NET MVC - Iframe Download Dialog not showing up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

I need to make a file download that displays a loading icon during the processing of the file (because I don't know how long it is going to take), I decided to use an iframe, the code runs fine, but the **problem is that the file download dialog box doesn't show up**.

I've tested in IE, Firefox and Chrome and it is not working in any of them.

Here's my code:

View:

```
<table id="progress" style="visibility:hidden">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <h4>please wait.</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="Ok" class="button" id="downloadButton">
</div>

<iframe id="iframe" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#downloadButton').click(function () {

            $('#progress').show();
            $('input:button').attr("disabled", true);

            $('#iframe').src = "@Url.Action("GenerateFile", "Files", null)";

            $('#iframe').load("GenerateFile", function () {
                $('input:button').attr("disabled", false);
                $('#progress').hide();
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Server side Action:

```
[HttpGet]       
public void GenerateFile(Filters viewModel)        
{        
    var result = GetCustomers().WithName(viewModel.Name);        
    StringBuilder file = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var customer in result)        
    {        
        // fill up the string builder with csv format       
    }        

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=Customers.csv");        
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/csv";        
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(file);        
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();        
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are multiple problems with this code. Try this:

```
public FileResult GenerateFile(Filters viewModel)
        {
            var result = GetCustomers().WithName(viewModel.Name);
            StringBuilder file = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var customer in result)
            {
                // fill up the string builder with csv format       
            }
            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.ToString());
            return File(content, "application/csv", "Customers.csv");
        }
```

and I think there is no jQuery method called src, so try this also:

```
$('#iframe').attr('src',url);
```

I assume you're using Razor syntax, so try this for your View code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<table id="progress" style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <h4>please wait.</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="Ok" class="button" id="downloadButton">
</div>

<iframe id="iframe" style="display: none"></iframe>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#downloadButton').click(function () {

                $('#progress').show();
                $('input:button').attr("disabled", true);

                var url = "@Url.Action("GenerateFile", "Files", null)";
$("#iframe").attr('src', url);

                $('#iframe').load("/Files/GenerateFile", function () {
                    $('input:button').attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#progress').hide();
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

And I also believe that you should specify an Action parameter in your jQuery load function, eg. $('#iframe').load("/Files/GenerateFile/parameter"...) because your GenerateFile action takes Filters parameter.

Comment: I've changed my server-side code to this as it definitely looks better, thanks already. Although the problem still occurs... If I'm not asking too much It'd be great if you could point what you dislike about my code to help me improve it.

Comment: Well, it worked, so I assume I should mark your answer as accepted, I'm just holding a bit to see if I get any other idea on this... You've spotted a problem that I didn't realize until now, I think there is not way for me to post my viewModel this way, I might have to try and find a different solution.

Comment: Another thing that I've noticed is that the action method gets called twice now, I guess it is because setting the src attribute makes the iframe invoke the method same way with jquery's load, so I guess I shouldn't mix them

Comment: You should definitely omit src attribute, and continue using jquery load function, that's the reason why it's being called 2 times. I overlooked it..